# All v4 Requests are Giving Error Code 403 (Forbidden)

Tags: python, bit.ly

I'm working with the Python Bit.ly API and trying to convert it to work with v4. Has anyone had any success with this? Specifically, I'm trying to pull the data for a user (specifically groups) which only v4 supports, so I cannot use the v3 API. This is the function (located in the bitly_api.py file):

```
def user_info(self, **kwargs):
    """return or update info about a user"""
    #data = self._call_oauth2("v3/user/info", kwargs)
    data = self._call_oauth2("v4/groups", kwargs)
    return data
```

The #data = self.... line works correctly, but returns the wrong information. The next line gives me the forbidden error. Does anyone have any idea of what else might need to be changed?

Python API link: https://github.com/bitly/bitly-api-python

Comment: Is the problem specific to this one API endpoint?  In other words, can you perform other operations that require the same authentication?  I'm curious if either a) you haven't authenticated correctly, or b) this particular call is unavailable to you somehow given the way you've authenticated. - I must admit that I know zero about this particular API.

Comment: It seems to be an issue with all v4 endpoints. I'm authenticating with an access token which theoretically should be okay based on the documentation

Comment: if the question is answered/problem fixed, post that as regular answer.